# ManipulationStarted fails to activate callback method

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, .net-4.5

I have a WPF Canvas with .NET-4.5.

I added events (which autocreated methods for) `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseDown`. Using `MessageBox`, I have confirmed these methods are called when a user clicks on the canvas, but I can't find a way to get the mouse position from `MouseButtonEventArgs`.

When I added events (and autocreated methods for) `ManipulationStarted` and `ManipulationStarting` those `MessageBox`es don't show up.

```
private void CenterCanvas_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
        MessageBox.Show("Doesn't show up");   // never shows up
}

private void CenterCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        MessageBox.Show("Shows up");   // shows up, but can't seem to get click position
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the mouse position from a `MouseEventArgs` you would have to call the [GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition.aspx) method.

```
private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var pos = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("MouseDown at {0}", pos);
}
```

For getting manipulation events you need to set [IsManipulationEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismanipulationenabled.aspx) to `true`. You may want to take a look at the [Touch and Manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#touch_and_manipulation) section in the MSDN [Input Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx).